ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = smallint Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types
I have this table:
@Entity
@Table(name = "system_accounts")
@Getter
@Setter
public class SystemAccounts {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "user_code")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private AccountType userCode;

}

.......

public enum AccountType {
  PERSONAL,
  CORPORATE
}

I use this SQL query:
@Query(value = """
                    SELECT ba.id,
                      FROM system_accounts
                     AND ba.user_code IN :accountTypes                                                                                                                       
            """, nativeQuery = true)
  Optional<List<SystemAccounts>> findAll(@Param("accountTypes") Set<AccountType> accountType);

I get error:
ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = smallint
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Do you know how I can use a Set<AccountType> in order to send a list of params for IN clause?

Your problem stems from your combination of
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
and a native query.
You could combine them as per:
Can I use enum parameter into JpaRepository nativeQuery?
or you could just rewrite your query in JPQL format.
e.g. rather than the adjusted after fixing some syntax errors:
    @Query(value = """
                    SELECT ba.id,
                      FROM system_accounts ba
                     WHERE ba.user_code IN :accountTypes                                                                                                                       
            """
            , nativeQuery = true)
    Optional<List<SystemAccount>> findAll(@Param("accountTypes") Set<AccountType> accountType);

you would write:
    @Query(value = """
                    SELECT a
                      FROM SystemAccounts a
                     WHERE a.userCode IN :accountTypes                                                                                                                       
            """)
    List<SystemAccount> findAllAccountType(@Param("accountTypes") Set<AccountType> accountType);

